# how to get selected value in controller using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in angularjs and trying to getting selected value in controller. It is working properly at front-end but the selected value getting undefined in controller, How can i access to selected value in controller?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


        <select ng-change="changed()" ng-model="selectedOption" class="form-control">
            <option ng-repeat="x in options" value="{{x.reason}}">{{x.reason}}</option>
        </select>
        {{selectedOption}}

    </div>


    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.options = [{reason: "Facebook"},
                {reason: "Instagram"},
                {reason: "Google"},
                {reason: "Twitter"},
                {reason: "SMS"}];
            $scope.changed = function () {
                console.log("selected Options: " + $scope.selectedOption);
            }
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code seems to be working

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. The console.log from controller works means the changed value is reflected in controller also

Comment: Its working.. how you want to use??

Answer (score 0):

Your code works.

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.options = [
   {reason : "Facebook"},
   {reason : "Instagram"},
   {reason : "Google"},
   {reason : "Twitter"},
   {reason : "SMS"},

];
$scope.changed= function() {
   console.log("selected Options: "+$scope.selectedOption);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<select ng-change="changed()" ng-model="selectedOption" class="form-control">
<option ng-repeat="x in options" value="{{x.reason}}">{{x.reason}}</option>
</select>{{selectedOption}}
</div>
```

Comment: If the code is working fine what is the need for this answer. Just a comment is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Seems everything is okay, just call `$scope.selectedOption` from anywhere in controller.

Comment: If the code is working fine what is the need for this answer. Just a comment is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Its working perfectly! I tried this in JSFiddle and its working as it should!

Even this is working too.

```
$scope.changed= function() {
   console.log("selected Options: "+$scope.selectedOption);
}
```

Look here: https://jsfiddle.net/vLam3pe0/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.selectedOption;
            $scope.options = [{reason: "Facebook"},
                {reason: "Instagram"},
                {reason: "Google"},
                {reason: "Twitter"},
                {reason: "SMS"}];
            $scope.changed = function () {
                console.log("selected Options: " + $scope.selectedOption);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I'm using it with ng-include so i was forgetting to add $parent.selectedOption, now it's working properly. thanks to all ..